# How to properly get a custom layer on gpu in Julia Flux?

Tags: julia, gpu, flux

As mentioned, I want to get GPU support for a custom layer. Here is the build-net part of my code:

```
# MyDense
struct MyDense
    d1
    d2     
end
MyDense(p::Pair) = MyDense(Dense(p), Dense(p))
(m::MyDense)(x) = m.d1(x) + m.d2(x)
# multiple-dispatch for gpu function on the custom layer
Flux.gpu(layer::MyDense) = MyDense(Flux.gpu(layer.d1), Flux.gpu(layer.d2))

# Define our model, a multi-layer perceptron with one hidden layer of size 3:
model = Chain(
    Dense(2 => 3, tanh),   # activation function inside layer
    BatchNorm(3),
    MyDense(3 => 2),
    softmax) |> gpu        # move model to GPU, if available
```

Reminded by @eliassno's answer in [this question](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-loaderror-argumenterror-cannot-take-the-cpu-address-of-a-cuarray-float32-2-cuda-mem-devicebuffer/66801), I wrote a new dispatch of `Flux.gpu` function for my custom layer. However, it still didn't work and gave me the error:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: cannot take the CPU address of a CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}
Stacktrace:
  [1] unsafe_convert(#unused#::Type{Ptr{Float32}}, x::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ CUDA C:\Users\Herr LU\.julia\packages\CUDA\DfvRa\src\array.jl:319
  [2] gemm!(transA::Char, transB::Char, alpha::Float32, A::Matrix{Float32}, B::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, beta::Float32, C::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ LinearAlgebra.BLAS C:\Users\Herr LU\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\LinearAlgebra\src\blas.jl:1514
  [3] gemm_wrapper!(C::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, tA::Char, tB::Char, A::Matrix{Float32}, B::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, _add::LinearAlgebra.MulAddMul{true, true, Bool, Bool})
    @ LinearAlgebra C:\Users\Herr LU\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:674
  [4] mul!
    @ C:\Users\Herr LU\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:161 [inlined]
  [5] mul!
    @ C:\Users\Herr LU\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:276 [inlined]
  [6] *
    @ C:\Users\Herr LU\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:148 [inlined]
  [7] (::Dense{typeof(identity), Matrix{Float32}, Vector{Float32}})(x::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ Flux C:\Users\Herr LU\.julia\packages\Flux\ZdbJr\src\layers\basic.jl:172
  [8] (::MyDense)(x::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ Main e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\FluxTrial.jl:14
  [9] macro expansion
    @ C:\Users\Herr LU\.julia\packages\Flux\ZdbJr\src\layers\basic.jl:53 [inlined]
 [10] _applychain(layers::Tuple{Dense{typeof(tanh), CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, BatchNorm{typeof(identity), CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Float32, CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, MyDense, typeof(softmax)}, x::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ Flux C:\Users\Herr LU\.julia\packages\Flux\ZdbJr\src\layers\basic.jl:53
 [11] (::Chain{Tuple{Dense{typeof(tanh), CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, BatchNorm{typeof(identity), CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Float32, CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, MyDense, typeof(softmax)}})(x::CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ Flux C:\Users\Herr LU\.julia\packages\Flux\ZdbJr\src\layers\basic.jl:51
 [12] top-level scope
    @ e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\FluxTrial.jl:25
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: You want `@functor MyDense`. Flux needs to be able to see the arrays inside the model, for a variety of purposes, not just `gpu`. And `gpu` does not just call itself recursively: https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/a50b18c6e8e7d326ea97d4fe00ec45a6d0a9652c/src/functor.jl#L189-L192